# Use modelbuilder to change default string from type nvarchar to varchar for specific fields in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using code-first migrations in EF6, and I need to change the default database type for string parameters in my DB from nvarchar to varchar for just one table/entity.

I have found how to do this globally by entering the following into my model building in my context class.

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("varchar"));
```

But this is not what I want, I only want it to affect my dbo.Contacts table.

Is there a way of only applying this only to one entity? I'd want to do it with model builder as I am using automatic migrations, and prefer to have my migrations built from the model build configurations.

Comment: I have found out how to do it using `modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().Property(x => x.CardNumber).HasColumnType("varchar");`. This fix is pretty simple I was just being a bit slow, I don't know if the question should just be deleted, just let me know if it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataAnnotations like:

```
[Column(“BlogDescription", TypeName="ntext")]
```

Or can try use Mappings with Fluent API.

see more: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-property-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx

Comment: Thanks I find the annotations much neater